kotlin android xml - overlapping shape, remove Border
there is an overlapping at the bottom right corner. It is a square lying under a rectangle. How to remove the overlapping and make it looks 1 complete object?

cardview (it is my rectangle)
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <!-- Content inside the CardView -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/no_border">

square xml code
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/square"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:rotation="45"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>


Can you try setting the background for the CardView directly

You need to set the card view elevation to 0 to make the shadow disappear. I have recreated the same UI with the code below.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="-30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_pointer"
        android:rotation="45"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:contentPadding="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FF007A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Please update your information"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="8dp"
            android:text="Update"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<!-- res/drawable/button_background.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

<!-- res/drawable/ic_pointer.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF007A" />
    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
</shape>


